# Spring3 - @Autowired

Tags: spring-mvc

This is my applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="JdbcUserDao" class="controller.User.JdbcUserDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>


<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
      p:driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"
      p:url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/TodoDb"
      p:username="root"
      p:password="root" />
```

This is my implDao class :

```
@Repository
public class JdbcUserDao implements IUserDao {

    private JdbcTemplate jt;
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
            jt = new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource); 
    }

    public JdbcTemplate getJt() {
        return jt;
    }

    public void setJt(JdbcTemplate jt) {
        this.jt = jt;
    }


    @Override
    public List<User> getUsers(final String username, final String password) {
        List<User> users = this.jt.query("SELECT username, password FROM USERS",
            new RowMapper<User>() {

                @Override
                public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {
                    User user = new User();
                    user.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
                    user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
                    return user;
                }
            });
        return users;
    }
}
```

Problems:

- this.dataSource available when it sets the dataSource through @Autowired like the configs in xml
- when I use dataSource in getUsers, it become null ?

Questions:

1. How can I get this works ?

I'm new to spring3 so I really need your help.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use autowiring, you need to add the following to your xml file configuration.

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

If it doesn't help then please add

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the AutowiredPostProcessor to the config

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
 </bean>
```

Comment: you rock! I have been trying to fix my very similar issue for past 4 days and I almost looked for answers in 1000's of google results. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the autowire to the set method instead of the property.

Answer (score 0):

you need to import the class which you are doing autowired without access modifiers in repository class file

```
com.<your project>.controller.User.JdbcUserDao
```

and spring annotation

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
@Repository
 public class JdbcUserDao implements IUserDao {

  @Autowired
  DataSource dataSource;
```